# Evaluation metrics for an RL model. How to select then?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, model-evaluation, importance-sampling, doubly-robust-estimator

I trained an RL model adapting the RL batch example ([Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/IntelLabs/coach/blob/59e08034c685c2b9c9d649ee0f00a90b8b6eed94/tutorials/4.%20Batch%20Reinforcement%20Learning.ipynb)) to the problem I was aiming to solve.

As for the training, everything went well but, even though the RL batch returned several evaluation metrics ('Evaluation Reward', 'Shaped Evaluation Reward','Success Rate', 'Inverse Propensity Score', 'Direct Method Reward','Doubly Robust', 'Weighted Importance Sampling','Sequential Doubly Robust',), I am not sure which one to use to evaluate the trained model.

Two metrics were proposed in the example to evaluate the problem: "Weighted Importance Sampling" and " Sequential Doubly Robust" (shown in the graph below).

[image]

Therefore, I would like to ask how to interpret those two metrics (what they calculate, evaluate and imply) and if one of the metrics shown above could be better used to evaluate the model.

I am also looking for some references (articles, books, etc) to better understand those metrics. I have already searched for some (like this article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02834), but I could not understand their explanation.